# Custom Sorting in Lucene.Net

Tags: c#, sorting, lucene, lucene.net, string-comparison

In `Lucene.Net` (`2.9.4`, but if it's possible in a later version that's still interesting to me), is it possible to create custom sorting algorithms, like you can for `C#` (`IComparable<>`)?

Two types that I'm having trouble with:

`100000`, `100000000`, `200000` Should be ordered `100000`, `200000`, `100000000`
and sorting based on less than, greater than: "`>10`", "`10 through 50`", "`50 through 100`", "`<100`"  (where it's assumed the ranges don't overlap)
Are sorting either of these ways possible in `Lucene` (or `Lucene.Net`)?

Comment: You can write a custom *Collector*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort numerically (as opposed to lexicographically), you should index that field as a [NumericField](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/2.9.4/html/6bb7a489-94e3-3411-845b-52009b58702f.htm):

```
Field myField = new NumericField("myIntField").setIntValue(100000);
```

Having done that, sorting on that field should get the numeric ordering you are looking for:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("myIntField", SortField.INT));
```

I'm not clear on what exactly you mean by sorting by ranges there, but indexed in this way, you would be able to query by range, using a [NumericRangeQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/2.9.4/html/951ba516-5f61-98e2-46f4-66a4c8bc6233.htm)

```
Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("myIntField", 10, 50, true, true);
```

Combining a set of range queries in a `BooleanQuery` with different boosts might be what you are looking for there.

Comment: To clarify on that last bit with the ranges- I'm literally trying to sort on those specific strings, as the Lucene data has saved values that say one of those four values. This is for a dropdown list where people would select one of those four specific values.

Comment: @JanusFenix - I don't think there is anything obvious out-of-the-box that would do that for you.  I would just index some sort of range identifier for them to sort on (like range:"<10", rangeid:1, etc.), and sort on that identifier instead.